# How to put label and radio circle in same line

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to make it look like it looks at the picture. 
[image]

I can't put label and radio "circle" in same line.

I was trying to add input class and set float: left but it makes a big space between those two.

```html
<fieldset>
        <legend>Choose car rental</legend>
            <label>mini<input type="radio" name="carclass" value="mini" value="mini"></label>
            <label>economy<input type="radio" name="carclass" value="economy"></label>
            <label>compact<input type="radio" name="carclass" value="compact"></label>
            <label>SUV<input type="radio" name="carclass" value="suv"></label>
            <label>VAN<input type="radio" name="carclass" value="van"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose optional equupment</legend>
        <label>child seat<input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="seat"></label>
        <label>GPS<input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="GPS"></label>
        <label>DVD player<input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="dvd"></label>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not nescesary to use a label tag for radio fields. Try adding your radio fields like this:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose car rental</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="mini"> Mini<br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="economy" checked> Economy<br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="compact"> Compact<br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="suv"> Suv<br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="van"> Van
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose optional equipment</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="eq" value="seat" checked> Seat<br>
  <input type="radio" name="eq" value="gps"> GPS<br>
  <input type="radio" name="eq" value="dvd"> dvd
</fieldset>
```

If you need a **clickable label** to select the radio field, then you would need labels with `for` attributes and add `id` attributes to the input fields. Like this:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose car rental</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" id="mini" value="mini">
  <label for="mini">Mini</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" id="economy" value="economy" checked>
  <label for="economy">Economy</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" id="compact" value="compact">
  <label for="compact">Compact</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" id="suv" value="suv">
  <label for="suv">Suv</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="carclass" id="van" value="van">
  <label for="van">Van</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose optional equipment</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="eq" id="seat" value="seat" checked>
  <label for="seat">Seat</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="eq" id="gps" value="gps">
  <label for="gps">GPS</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="eq" id="dvd" value="dvd">
  <label for="dvd">dvd</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: No, it's not necessary to use label tags together with inputs. But without a `label` with a `for` attribute the text is not clickable, only the input itself. It's considered a web standard to have the text next to an input be clickable.

Comment: Very true @Emil Carlsson. Thanks for pointing that out! I have added a second example in solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<input>` before the `<label>`, like so:

```html
<label>This is the label</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio">
```

If you want the radio to be selected when clicking on the label you have to add an ID to the input and reference that ID by using the `for` attribute. Like so:

```html
<label for="radio1">This is the label</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="radio">
```

If you want the label and radio on their own line, add a `<br />` after the `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css like this

```
fieldset label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Place the `<input>` tag before the `<label>` tag and add a `<br>` after `<label>`

> ```
> <input> <label></label> <br>
> ```

**CSS**

The essential styles are:

> ```
> input, label {height: [line-height]; line-height: [height]; vertical-align: middle}
> ```

The rest of the CSS is either *suggested* or *required*. Required styles meaning to apply in the current layout, so it may or may not work as well under different circumstances. See comments in the demo.

BTW when a `<form>` is submitted the values of each form control (ex. `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc) with a `[name]` attribute is collected then sent to the server. A radio button group commonly share a `[name]` because of its singular nature (normally only one radio can be selected), but if other types of form controls share a `[name]` then the values will be collected into an array with said `[name]`. Nothing wrong with that in of itself but just FYI since the checkboxes share the same `[name=eq]`.

```css
/* Suggested */

:root {
  font: 400 16px/1.3 Verdana;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

fieldset {
  width: fit-content;
}


/* Required */

input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1.3rem; /* Essential */
  line-height: 1.3rem;  /* Essential */
  vertical-align: middle;  /* Essential */
}

input {
  width: 1rem;
}

[type=radio] {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose car rental</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="mini">
    <label>mini</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="economy">
    <label>economy</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="compact">
    <label>compact</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="suv">
    <label>SUV</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="carclass" value="van">
    <label>VAN</label><br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose optional equipment</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="seat">
    <label>child seat</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="GPS">
    <label>GPS</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="dvd">
    <label>DVD player</label><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your just putting the text before the input dont use `<br>`
 now you can use if you want them to wrap use on fieldset display:inline-flex;without targeting label or display:inline-block  and you set the label to display:block

```css
label{display:block;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
        <legend>Choose car rental</legend>
            <label><input type="radio" name="carclass" value="mini">mini</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="carclass" value="economy">economy</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="carclass" value="compact">compact</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="carclass" value="suv">SUV</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="carclass" value="van">VAN</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose optional equupment</legend>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="seat">child seat</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="GPS">GPS</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="eq" value="dvd">DVD player</label>
    </fieldset>
```